# Coin toss problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> A fair coin is repeatedly tossed until a head is obtained. Calculate the probability that this experiment will not end after the first $6194$ attempts, given that it has not ended after the first $6192$ attempts.

I know we can solve this using geometric distribution, but I'm having some trouble applying it correctly. Do I need to find $P(X > r)$, for $r = 6194$?

We know that the experiment has not ended after $6192$ tosses, so the probability we're looking for must be multiplied by $(\dfrac{1}{2})^{6192}.$ Where do we go from here? I'm not sure what to do on the $6193^{rd}$ toss. Can someone please explain how to solve this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Each flip is independent, so $6192$ is a red herring. The answer is $\frac12\cdot\frac12=\frac14$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When *given* that the experiment does *not* end until *after* 6192 attempts, then the only way it will end *after* 6194 attempts is that it does not end on either the 6193rd or 6194th attempt.

Since these two trials are independent of all the prior trials, their successes do not influence the results of these two trials.

So the (conditional) probability we seek is merely the probability these two trials fail.

$$\mathsf P(X>6194\mid X>6192)=\left({\tfrac 1 2}\right)^2$$

---

Alternatively, since you have already calculated $\mathsf P(X>6912)$, then you can do the same for $\mathsf P(X>6194)$.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X>6194\mid X>6192)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X>6194\cap X>6192)}{\mathsf P(X>6192)}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X>6194)}{\mathsf P(X>6192)}&&{\tiny\{X>a+2\}\cap\{X>a\}\iff \{X>a+2\}}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf 1/2^{6194}}{1/2^{6192}}\end{align}$$